# Return value from bash to Ansible task

Tags: bash, ansible

I call a bash script from an ansible task. The script performs certain actions and returns a dynamic URL, say `https://example.com/v1`, to console.

I was wondering if it is possible to parse the URL into an ansible variable? An option is to write it to file, but I'd like to avoid this approach if possible.

Comment: How do you call that bash script? Via `shell`? Then just `register` the task and you'll get [its  `result` output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction,  @β.εηοιτ.βε. Will accept if you post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering the output of a task in Ansible is done via the key [`register`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables).
It can be added on any tasks you wish to reuse the output.

And in you case, since your script does write to the console, so to the [stdout stream](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-lpic1-103-4/#input-output-and-streams), you should use the [`stdout`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-stdout) field.

Given the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - shell: echo 'https://example.com/v1' 
      register: url

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ url.stdout }}"
```

It yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [shell] *******************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "https://example.com/v1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```